# Service deployed on secure cluster not working

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I deployed Project on secure cluster.I am able to see application deployed in Explorer but it is not working when I try to acess the webpage it is showing `{"Error":{"Code":"E_INVALIDARG","Message":"Invalid argument"}}`
After sometime Explorer is showing Warning
[image: Explorer]

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?